# zle reset-prompt prevents browsing history with arrow keys

Tags: zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

I just installed zsh and oh-my-zsh (my previous shell was bash). My `.zshrc` is completely unmodified from oh-my-zsh's default settings. The "git" plugin is the only enabled plugin (it's enabled by default).

I created a very simple theme using [this technique](https://askubuntu.com/a/360172/565424):

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PROMPT='[%D{%L:%M:%S}] '
TMOUT=1
TRAPALRM() {
  zle reset-prompt
}
```

After enabling this theme, I am finding that the up and down arrow keys do not properly recall my history:

- When I press the up arrow once, my most recent command is recalled, as expected.
- When I press the up arrow a second time, nothing happens. I expected my next-most-recent command to be recalled.
- When I press the down arrow after pressing the up arrow the first time, nothing happens. I expected the prompt to go back to the empty prompt I started with.

If I replace my `.zshrc` with *only* the contents of the script above (essentially using the prompt settings from the theme but disabling oh-my-zsh), my up and down arrows work as expected.

If I go back to my oh-my-zsh `.zshrc` and comment out the `zle reset-prompt` line in my theme, my history works fine (but the clock is no longer live).

How can I use both oh-my-zsh and `zle reset-prompt` without causing my up/down arrows to behave differently? Is this a bug in oh-my-zsh, or a configuration error?

Comment: if i increase the TMOUT, it becomes clear that the arrow keys work fine until the TRAPALRM gets fired, then it locks up.

Comment: What version of zsh is this?  I don't see this problem on zsh 5.7.1.

Comment: @phord i don't know but when i got rid of oh-my-zsh the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function instead

```bsh
TRAPALRM() {
    case "$WIDGET" in
        expand-or-complete|self-insert|up-line-or-beginning-search|down-line-or-beginning-search|backward-delete-char|.history-incremental-search-backward|.history-incremental-search-forward)
            :
            ;;

        *)
            zle reset-prompt
            ;;
    esac
}
```

Basically, this runs `zle reset-prompt` only when the `WIDGET` is not inside the case. You can add the list of widgets for ignoring the `reset-prompt` there by seperating with `|`

The problem is, `TMOUT` actually specifies the timeout of a shell. After the shell timeout, it will fire `SIGALRM` signal and exit the shell. The `TRAPALRM()` function will catch the `SIGALRM` signals and intercept the exit, while executing the defined function instead.

Your up/down arrows does not behave differently, instead it fires when the prompt is resetting, thus behave strangely. The function above will not run `zle reset-prompt` when you are typing or scrolling through history, and removes the lag. The only drawbacks is that the prompt won't be able to update after you type, until you  do something that is outside of the widgets (like pressing `ENTER` which fires the `accept-line` widgets).